# AFNetworking and getting wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I know this issue has been reported on SO numerous times (I clicked through dozens of the questions/solutions), however, i'm really not getting this.

I have a POST request via `AFJSONRequestOperation`. In the success block, I do the following:

```
       NSString *errorString = [ErrorHandler getErrorMessage:[jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"ERROR"]];
       UIAlertView *mainAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

       [self performSelector:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:mainAlert afterDelay:.5]; // Doesn't work
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert:) userInfo:mainAlert repeats:NO]; // Doesn't work!


// Function that gets called
- (void)showAlert:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    UIAlertView *mainAlert = timer.userInfo;
    [mainAlert show];
}
```

I tried with the multiple solutions that were posted on SO (`performSelector` and `NSTimer` along with some of my own ideas). However, I keep getting that infamous message. I'm not doing anything in my `viewDidLoad` method other than initializing some variables. Is there anything else that could be tried for this? I'm programming for iOS 5.0 and this is being done on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! And honestly, not sure how this even an issue, must be something in the framework.

I had 5 `UITextField`'s, and i was sending data to the server. I had to `resignFirstResponder` and it worked properly.